# Calling Function from other VC

Tags: ios, swift, function, func

I'm trying to call function from one ViewController to another because in One I have PageMenuVC(VC where I'm trying to call function cause of BarButtonItem and in another I have tableview which is displayed in PageMenuVC).

**Func in TableViewController**:

```
func doEdit(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        editButton.title = "Upraviť"
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        editButton.title = "Hotovo"
        self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Calling in PageMenuVC**

I'm Calling

```
@IBAction func doEdit(sender: AnyObject) {
    MojeTesty().doEdit() // What should be in doEdit?(here?)?
}
```

Comment: What does `MojeTesty()` function *assuming it is a function) does in your PageMenuVC? Assuming it returns your instance of TableViewController, you cam simply call `MojeTesty().doEdit(sender)`

Comment: Yeah. But If i use in brackets sender as you said it won't be "working" because button didn't change the name of button what's in function.

Comment: It should change the editButton (which I guess is a Outlet) isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes editButton is a Outlet and yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as compilation is concerned, the solution to this sort of thing is declare your `doEdit` like this:

```
func doEdit(sender:AnyObject?) {
```

Now you can pass `nil`, since you have no real `sender`.

However, this won't have any effect, because when you say `MojeTesty()` you get a *different instance* of this class — not the real one you want to talk to. You need to stop and get a grip on the basic concepts of object-oriented programming (class and instance); you'll never be able to program for iOS if you don't understand what an instance is.